# Reg multiple synchronised block with multiple JVM's

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, jvm, distributed-computing

I have a java application deployed on WAS.It receives request from WPS(Websphere Process Server) and inserts the data into Oracle DB.
Inorder to avoid multithreading issues,I wrote the code in a synchronised block.Now the application is working  fine on Dev env(single JVM).
I came to know that QA has multiple JVM's. I heared that synchronised block doesn't work on multiple JVM's,so I am worried whether my application works in QA env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synchronized keyword works using locks against instances in the JVM where the method is invoked, so you won't get any guarantees of thread safety if your application is running across multiple JVMs. (In fact, you will only get a guarantee in a single JVM if you are careful about what you synchronize *on*.)

This mechanism is well documented, including the [Oracle JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html), but blog posts on the topic might be easier to understand.

I don't think we can tell you whether your application will work in "QA" from the information you've given. It depends on the detail of what's being done. For example, let's assume that WPS is sending requests out to your JVMs and you just have to insert them all in your database. If you were inserting into the database using a primary key that is a number incrementing in your JVM then you have problems as a result that possibly won't occur with your synchronized code. On the other hand, if you're generating a random primary ID, or letting the database generate IDs for you, then it's rather less likely to be a problem.

It might help if you think about what scenarios could cause your application to fail or do the wrong thing. Then if you're not sure how to proceed you'll at least be able to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized blocks doesn't work across JVMs, so you may expect strange behavior if you strongly rely on that.  You should use database transactions and locking to avoid concurrent access to database from multiple JVMs.

Unfortunately you problem description is to vague to tell, if your application will work correctly in clustered environment.

Comment: Thanks for your repsones.I am generating the primary key using sequences "SELECT SQ_ATTRIB.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL".QA env is clustered.Other than using database transactions,can you please  suggest any work around to my code,so that I don't get any strange behavior when deployed to QA

Comment: @krishnamovva The nextval is safe to use from concurrent database connections. You dont need to do any synchronization in your code to get unique values. Database engine takes care about it. So remove any synchronized blocks, if their only reason was to ensure serial access to nextval.

Comment: Yes,The only reason to have synchronised block in my code to ensure serial access. Do I get any errors when I deploy to QA(multiple JVM's) after removing synchronised block.

Comment: @krishnamovva I cannot guarantee that :) But they shouldnt be related to nextval.

Comment: Thanks Gas!!.Let me give a try